# Append to an existing elasticsearch array field using python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have the following ES object:

```
    {
      "_index": "index_name",
      "_type": "my_type",
      "_id": "12345678-abcd-9012-efgh-3456ijkl7890"
      "_source": {
        "apps": [
          {
            "processName": "process_name_1",
            "name": "app_name_1",
            "VersionName": "version_1"
          },
          {
            "processName": "process_name_2",
            "name": "app_name_2",
            "VersionName": "version_2"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

I want to add another object to the "apps" array while keeping the existing data so it looks like the following:

```
    {
      "_index": "index_name",
      "_type": "my_type",
      "_id": "12345678-abcd-9012-efgh-3456ijkl7890"
      "_source": {
        "apps": [
          {
            "processName": "process_name_1",
            "name": "app_name_1",
            "VersionName": "version_1"
          },
          {
            "processName": "process_name_2",
            "name": "app_name_2",
            "VersionName": "version_2"
          },
          {
            "processName": "process_name_3",
            "name": "app_name_3",
            "VersionName": "version_3"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

As you see, I only added a third "app" to these apps objects. I need to do this in Python using the elasticsearch module. All my attempts either overwrite the existing items or do not work. I tried using the "ctx._source.apps+= newapps" scripting, but with Python, it seems to just append a new object named "scripts" and the new data, alongside the "apps" object, instead of just add to the "apps" object. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work, you can refer to [update api](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.update) for python for more info. You need to put your `script` inside `body` param

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch()

es.update(
    index="index_name",
    doc_type="my_type",
    id="12345678-abcd-9012-efgh-3456ijkl7890",
    body={"script": "ctx._source.apps += app",
          "params": {
              "app": {
                  "processName": "process_3",
                  "name": "name_3",
                  "VersionName": "version_3"
              }
            }
          }
)
```

Comment: This can't be done that way as groovy scripting is disabled and is not something I am allowed to enable.

Comment: which version of ES you are using?

Comment: using AWS ElasticSearch, so version 1.5.2 . This is for a business use, so I will not be able to enable groovy.

Comment: then how are you doing in right now? do you have ability to store script file in config folder?

Comment: Sorry, when I said I tried the "script" thing before, it used a "doc" tag, which is why it didn't work as expected. So using a script is out for me.

Comment: ok, got it. We had the same problem with AWS service and thats why created our own cluster.